# sikuli is not finding image files

Tags: java, maven, sikuli

Trying out Sikuli in Java with sikulixapi 1.1.0, but it doesn't find my image files.

```
      screen.click("images/Terminal.png");
```

Maven (shade) put my src/main/resources/images into the JAR's toplevel "images" directory as expected.  But running the uberjar doesn't find the image.

```
~/hello $ java -cp target/hello.jar hello.TestSikuli
 [error] Image: could not be loaded: file://Users.../hello/images/Terminal.png
```

It's looking in the current directory (happens to be the project directory), not in the JAR. I printed out the imagePath in the program, and it's an empty array.

How do I get it (perhaps with imagePath.add?) to search the invoked JAR?
I had imagined it would look there by default.

---

Another thing I tried:

```
URL u = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/Terminal.png");
Region r = screen.find(u);
```

But that blows up; if I pass a URL as shown here, I get "invalid parameter"; if I pass the .toString, I get:

```
FindFailed: Region: doFind: Image not loadable:
jar:file:/Users/.../Sikulix/j/hello/target/hello-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/images/Terminal.png
```

There doesn't seem to be a stream input interface in Sikluix, so maybe this just can't be done.

Answer (score 6):

This worked:

```
  ImagePath.add(TestSikuli.class.getCanonicalName() + "/images");
```

There may also be a workaround of loading the image into memory.
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/232217

Answer (score 0):

import this library

```
import org.sikuli.basics.ImageLocator;
```

and use this function to locate your image directory path

```
ImageLocator.setBundlePath("path to img directory");
```

and to execute your **jar** file run the following commands

```
  cd "your directory"

  java -jar hello.jar
```

Comment: I am asking about loading a file that's in the JAR, not in the filesystem.

Comment: Image locator is currently deprecated.

Comment: Image locator is currently deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Screen s1 = new Screen();
s.dragDrop("Drag elemtn location.png","Drag elemtn location.png");
```

You can give the element path location which you want to drag and same as drop.